# Does WAL cause Hbase writing performance inefficient

Tags: hbase

The book says that one RegionServer only have one opened WAL file. So I'm wondering if I have multiple writing requests to one RegionServer at the same time, so will the WAL become the bottleneck of writing, since the file lock will change the parallel writing to very slow sequential writing? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here about wals : https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_multiwal

It says you can have parallel wal writing after 1.0 version and if you need, you can split wal files for regions, so you can have more than one wal file for a RegionServer.

And if your data is not so important, you can disable wal writing for individual Put operations.